# Language problem is causing updatting problem!

Tags: directory, system, language-support

I searched so much but still haven't found any serious answer for this. I installed ubuntu 13.10 in english and i changed later the system language in greek. So everything turned into greek. When i had to update the flash player in order to work better i had to write in the terminal some orders to open (through the terminal) my folders so i could open-decompress what i had downloaded to update the adobe flash player.

When i changed the system language back to english the directory folders, such as music, documents, pictures and videos didn't translated back in english. That means that i still can't update adobe flash player because i was so bad to dare to change the language.

Please help me. I've already been trying to find a solution for more than 6 hours. The best solution would be to find a way to fully translate the pc in english so i don't have the same problem in the future again using the terminal. By the way when i choosed "greek language" i was asked if i want to change also the folders and i pressed yes. Plus, i choosed not to be asked again this question. What is going on? Is there any solution to this?

If you somebody is willing to help please explain everything in details because i am new quite new in ubuntu.

Thanks,
Giorgos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that your display language is English again, you can change back the names of the content folders in your home directory to English by running this command:

```
xdg-user-dirs-update --force
```

Comment: you are amazing. It actually DID work. Thank you so much  :))))

Comment: @Georgios: You're welcome.